# Error: write EPIPE while using imagemagick To write a lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-imagemagick, epipe

```
var gm = require("gm").subClass({ imageMagick: true });

function conversion(image) {
   const image = gm(image);
   image.orientation(function(err, value) {
            if (err) {
                 console.log("Error Occurred :",err);
              }
}
```

**While accessing image.orientation this is the error which occurs.**

```
Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:786:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:798:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at gm._spawn (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:253:18)
    at gm._exec (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:190:17)
    at gm.proto.<computed> [as orientation] (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/getters.js:68:12) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

**These are some steps which i have already performed.**

1. i have tried installing both imagemagick and graphicsmagick. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm
2. Also there was suggestion to reinstall imagemagick and graphicsmagick and testing after restarting system. it also didn't worked
3. i am using Ubuntu , npm gm version:"^1.23.1", node version : nodejs12.x